# Cannot run " setwd " and " read.csv " in php R script

Tags: php, r, exec, rscript

I try to make WebApp using php & R . this is my php code:

```
exec("/usr/bin/Rscript /home/bella/Downloads/htdocs/laut/script.r $N");

$nocache = rand();
echo("<img src='tmp.png?$nocache' />");
```

And this is my script.r code:

```
slices <- c(10, 12,4, 16, 8)
lbls <- c("US", "UK", "Australia", "Germany", "France")

png(filename="tmp.png", width=600, height=600)
pie(slices, labels = lbls, main="Pie Chart of Countries")
dev.off()
```

Everything work fine.

Then, i change slices data and store it in csv. I change script.r code:

```
setwd("/home/bella/Downloads/DATA")
slices<-read.csv("country.csv",header=T,sep=";",dec=",")
lbls <- c("US", "UK", "Australia", "Germany", "France")

png(filename="tmp.png", width=600, height=600)
pie(as.matrix(slices), labels = lbls, main="Pie Chart of Countries")
dev.off()
```

I run it, but tmp.png file not updated.

It seem that my R code "`setwd`" and "`read.csv`" didn't run.

(i try both script in R and running well)

Why this happen? How to get data from csv file using R script in php?

Comment: Does php or the web server sandbox you?

Comment: i dont know how to test it

Comment: Your web server error log is a good place to start -- and adding log messages may help.

Comment: i already check it. but, there are no error happen

Comment: change permission & access to file and folder, and everything work fine 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change permission & access to related file and folder, and everything work fine

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First thing `pie(slices, labels = lbls, main="Pie Chart of Countries")` only depends on the objects `slices` and `lbls`. If you don't change these objects after reading in other data (notice that in `R` you can have more than one active data set - in contrast to some other software like SAS etc.), then your pie chart also won't change. So you need to have a comand like `slices <- data1[, "NAME OF YOUR DESIRED VARIABLE"]`. Second thing, your question doesn't show how `x` in `hist` looks like.